# Packing multiple values into a “key”

Tags: c++

I was reading an article on draw call buffers in game engines: https://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/?p=86

Such a buffer holds the draw calls before they are submitted to the GPU and the buffer is usually sorted before submitting according to multiple values (depth, material, viewport, etc.).

The approach in the article suggests to store the draw calls under keys that provide context such as viewport, material and depth using values packed together such that the sort order starts at the MSB and ends at LSB. Eg. first 2 bits is viewport, next 24 bits is depth, next 10 bits is material ID and so on. It should then be easy/quick to sort afterwards when actually drawing by sorting on this key. However, I am struggling as to:

- how this is implemented in practice,
- the actual speedup over simply having a struct with multiple members and implementing a comparison function that compares each of the struct members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how this is implemented in practice

The article mentions bitfields, which are like this:

```
struct S {
    unsigned viewport : 2;
    unsigned depth : 24;
    unsigned material : 10;
    unsigned unused : 28; // always some fixed value like zero
};
```

Then when you want to compare two of them, just use `memcmp(&s1, &s2, 8)` which a good compiler will turn into a single 64-bit comparison.  Beware: `memcmp()` just compares one byte at a time starting from the given addresses, so pay attention to your machine's endianness such that your "most significant" bytes come first in the struct.  This may require adding some padding between unusual-size fields.

As for "the actual speedup over simply having a struct with multiple members and implementing a comparison function that compares each of the struct members", you'd have to try that on your specific platform to find out.  Could be faster, could be slower, could be the same.  If you use normal-width integers instead of bitfields, you will consume more memory, but certain operations may be faster (or slower).